# como actualizar los campo de un servidor remoto con los datos del un servidor local en SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

Buenos dias compañero queria saber si me ayudaban

Quiero actualizar los datos de un servidor remoto con los datos de un servidor local ambos son Sql server  le dejo mi scrip para ver si me pueden ayudar

```
  UPDATE [NRIVERA-PC\MSSQLSERVER2019].SGC_Blue.dbo.Maestro 
    SET 
    Maestro.Lakwh = t2.Lakwh,
    Maestro.Fecha_desde=t2.Fecha_desde,
    Maestro.Leido=t2.Leido
    FROM Maestro m ,
    (
        select 
            Lakwh, Fecha_desde, leido, 
            nic, ruta, Estado,
            itinerario
        FROM Maestro m 
        WHERE m.ruta =150 
        AND m.estado IN('CUE_AC','SER_NU','SER_CO')
        AND m.itinerario IN (1,2,4) 
    ) t2
    WHERE m.nic=t2.nic and m.ruta =150 
    AND m.estado IN('CUE_AC','SER_NU','SER_CO')
    AND m.itinerario IN (1,2,4)
```

Lo que deseo es que me actualice solo los datos que tengo en el servidor local al servidor remoto con esta condicion

```
WHERE m.ruta =150 
AND m.estado IN('CUE_AC','SER_NU','SER_CO')
       AND m.itinerario IN (1,2,4)
```

Pero el error es que me actualiza todos los campo de la tabla con el primer valor de la tabla del servidor local donde me deberia actualizar los datos con la condicion que le pongo.

Espero su tan amable ayuda

Comment: Cómo te podemos ayudar? Tienes un error? No se actualiza? El server no conecta? **Qué tipo de ayuda esperas**?

Comment: ya corrigi la pregunta

Comment: Hola! Bienvenidx a SOes. Gracias por editar la pregunta. En mi caso al menos, no logro entender qué problema tiene este UPDATE. Por la sintaxis, entiendo que ya tienes un linked server configurado. ¿Qué pasa cuando cambias la subconsulta para que use la condición que dices? O cómo quieres aplicar la condición. Incluso con unos datos de prueba y una salida esperada sería más fácil entender qué quieres que pase

Comment: volvi a redactar la pregunta

Comment: Uhmm... Me parece que todavía no está claro lo que pides. *Lo que deseo es que me actualice solo los datos que tengo en el servidor local al servidor remoto con esta condicion* -> Esto es una pregunta? Ya intentaste correr el update? Existe algún mensaje de error?

Comment: si el error es que me actualiza todos los campo de la tabla con el primer valor de la tabla del servidor local donde me deberia actualizar los datos con la condicion que le pongo

Comment: Por favor inlcuye eso en la pregunta. Incluye el error, datos de muestra, resultado esperado, resultado obtenido. Todo lo que creas que necesitamos para poder analizar y resolver el problema

Answer (score 0):

El problema es de entender qué parte de la sentencia le aplica a qué.

Tienes un UPDATE... SET... WHERE. Eso es lo básico. Le dices qué quieres actualizar (`UPDATE alguna_tabla`), le dices qué columnas quieres afectar (`SET una_columna = algo`) y le dices cómo filtrar las filas *de lo que indicaste en el UPDATE* para no afectar todo (`WHERE condiciones sobre alguna_tabla`). Fíjate que el WHERE no filtra lo que le pongo a la tabla; filtra **las filas que voy a modificar en la tabla destino**

Tú tienes:

- `UPDATE blablabla.Maestro` y pinta bien
- `SET Maestro.Lakwh = t2.Lakwh, Maestro.Fecha_desde=t2.Fecha_desde,     Maestro.Leido=t2.Leido` y también pinta bien
- Luego usas un truco de SQL Server y es decirle que saque esos valores a asignar de alguna parte (el FROM). Ese FROM es una subconsulta y todo pinta bien.
- Al final, tienes `WHERE m.nic=t2.nic and m.ruta =150 AND m.estado IN('CUE_AC','SER_NU','SER_CO') AND m.itinerario IN (1,2,4)` y, si te fijas, son todas condiciones sobre lo que tienes el en FROM. Esto está mal. Ahí no dices qué columnas de la tabla `blablabla.Maestro` debe afectar. Ahí le estás hablando de lo que le dijiste en el FROM (que, además, ya la subconsulta tiene ese WHERE).

Entonces, en el WHERE de la subconsulta van los filtros sobre la tabla local, en el WHERE "de afuera" van los filtros sobre `blablabla.Maestro` que es la tabla remota. Al darle condiciones de la tabla local en el WHERE de la tabla remota, estás abriendo portales a multiversos y todo va a salir mal.

Lo que aún no se entiende (y si relees, verás por qué te dije que pusieras datos de prueba pa entender), es a qué te refieres con *que me actualice solo los datos que tengo en el servidor local al servidor remoto con esta condicion*. En tu mente puede tener sentido, pero acá desde otro compu no se entiende. Si pones una tabla de ejemplo con dos registros y pones cómo debería quedar la tabla remota después de la consulta, te vamos a entender mejor.

Como aún no te entiendo eso, no sabría decirte si simplemente debes:

a) quitar el WHERE externo, o

b) cambiar los `m.` en el WHERE externo por `blablabla.Maestro` para que apunte a la tabla remota.

Comment: Te diría que esto es un comentario y no una respuesta, pero 1 ya lo sabes, y 2 esta respuesta/comentario es necesaria(o). Creo que esta pregunta está muy difícil de responder. OP puede buscar "update from join" o "update desde join" en google para obtener ejemplos que le ayuden